# Enable Inverse Document Frequency and disable term frequency and field length norms

Tags: elasticsearch

I wants to disable TF (Term Frequency) and Field length norms for calculating relevance score of elastic documents. In elastic search documents it shows how to disable TF

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type":          "string",
          "index_options": "docs" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And field length norms

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "norms": { "enabled": false } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I wants to know how to only enable IDF and disable other two? Does elastic search uses all 3 methods for relevance score by default ?